# Android text size for different resolutions

Tags: android

Should i use multiple folders for differentes resolutions?

For example:

- values_mdpi : 10sp
- values_hdpi: 12sp
- values_xhdpi: 15sp

Or textApperance is enough and we dont need folders for each screen? What are the best pratices

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different `values` folder for each dimension you want to target. In each `values` folder you can have a dimens.xml file that you can use to define a text size. ( I haven't androided in a while so hopefully the folder and xml file name are correct).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify only one size for your font as **sp** means **scale-independent pixels**

Your text will have the same size on all devices.

I advice you to read these two links to understand multiple resolutions on Android :

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

[What is the difference between "px", "dp", "dip" and "sp" on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Comment: Well i did it and i got different results :\